# MAC check failed when decrypting large files

Tags: python, stream, pycrypto

I want to encrypt and decrypt large files. My strategy is to write `seal` and `open_seal` below to handle en(de)cryption of data as a single byte array. For large files, I would read the file chunk by chunk, each time calling those functions to en(de)crypt the read-off chunk of data.

The program works when doing 1 whole chunk. For large files, I'd call `dark` to encrypt, which works by calling `seal` on each chunk read off the stream. To decrypt I call `light,` which calls `open_seal` to decrypt each of the encrypted chunk. Encryption didn't return any problem, but decryption failed with MAC check error.

```py
def seal(self,data):
        dataout = bytearray()
        session_key = get_random_bytes(16)

        # Encrypt the session key with the public RSA key
        cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(self.recipient_key)
        enc_session_key = cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key)

        # Encrypt the data with the AES session key
        cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX)
        ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(data)

        for x in (enc_session_key, cipher_aes.nonce, tag, ciphertext):
            dataout += x
        return bytes(dataout)

def open_seal(self,data):
        #raise Exception if private_key empty
        #private_key = RSA.import_key(khandle)
        #private_key = RSA.import_key(private_key)
        def split_data(chunks):
            i = 0
            for x in chunks:
                i += x
                yield data[i-x:i]

        enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = \
        [x for x in split_data((self.private_key.size_in_bytes(),16,16,len(data)))]


        # Decrypt the session key with the private RSA key
        cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(self.private_key)
        session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)

        # Decrypt the data with the AES session key
        cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
        plaindata = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
        return plaindata
#below is in the child class, hence calling super()

def dark(self):
    while True:
        data_plain = self.stream.read(deadStream.CHUNK)
        if data_plain:
          data_encrypted = super().seal(data_plain)
          yield data_encrypted
        else:
          break
def light(self):
    while True:
        data_encrypted = self.stream.read(deadStream.CHUNK)
        if data_encrypted:
          data_plain = super().open_seal(data_encrypted)
          yield data_plain
        else:
          break
```

I expected the output to be piecing each of the decrypted chunks